# Error: object of abstract class "Sphere" not allowed. and Error: no operator "=" matches these operands

Tags: c++

I've been trying to resolve a error for the last day or so and can't seem to work it through.
It's the kind of error that the fix is probably very easy :S
I tried to search for similar questions but the fixes don't apply.

**main.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int width, height;
    std::vector<Obj*> world;

    world.push_back(new Sphere(Vec(0, 0, -22), 2, Vec(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), true));

    (...)

    return 0;
}
```

**The error is found when I try to create a Sphere.**

Relevant classes
**Obj.h**

```
class Obj
{
public:
    Vec color;
    bool culling;

    virtual bool intersect(const Vec &ray_orig, Vec &ray_dir, float *t0 = NULL, float *t1 = NULL) = 0;
};
```

**Sphere.h**

```
class Sphere: public Obj
{
public:
    Vec center;                         
    float radius, radius2;                

    Sphere(Vec center, float radius, Vec color, bool culling);

    bool intersect(const Vec &ray_orig, Vec &ray_dir, float *t0 = NULL, float *t1 = NULL);
};
```

**Sphere.c**

```
Sphere::Sphere(Vec center, float radius, Vec color, bool culling){
    this->center = center;
    this->radius = radius;
    this->color = color;
    this->culling = culling;
}


bool Sphere::intersect(const Vec &ray_orig, Vec &ray_dir, float *t0 = NULL, float *t1 = NULL) {...}
```

These second error appears when I do **this->color = color;**. Not sure if they are related.

**Vec** is a simple struct with 3 variables.

If you need more information I'll add as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Jose

**EDIT**

Sorry for the delay.

**intersect(...)** is the only function in the obj class. Is there anyway to maintain the abstraction since there are several *objects*(sphere,box,...).

As requested here goes the definition of vec.h

**vec.h**

```
    struct Vec {

        float x, y, z;

        Vec() {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;}
        Vec(float val) {x = val, y = val, z = val;}
        Vec(float x_val,float y_val,float z_val) {x = x_val, y = y_val, z = z_val;}
        Vec(const Vec& copy) : x(copy.x), y(copy.y), z(copy.z) { }

        Vec operator+ (const Vec& p) const {
            return Vec(x + p.x, y + p.y, z + p.z);
        }

        Vec operator- (const Vec& p) const {
            return Vec(x - p.x, y - p.y, z - p.z);
        }

        Vec& operator += (const Vec& p) {
            x += p.x; y += p.y; z += p.z;
            return *this;
        }

        Vec& operator -= (const Vec& p) {
            x -= p.x; y -= p.y; z -= p.z;
            return *this;
        }

        Vec operator* (const float f) const {
            return Vec(f * x, f * y, f * z);
        }

        Vec& operator*= (const float f) {
            x *= f; y *= f; z *= f;
            return *this;
        }

        Vec operator/ (const float f) const {
            float inv = 1.f / f;
            return Vec(inv * x, inv * y, inv * z);
        }

        Vec& operator/= (const float f) {
            float inv = 1.f / f;
            x *= inv; y *= inv; z *= inv;
            return *this;
        }

Vec& operator= (const Vec& p) {
        x = p.x; y = p.y; z = p.z;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator== (const Vec& p) {
        if(x == p.x && y == p.y && z == p.z)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

        float length_squared() const {
            return x*x + y*y + z*z;
        }

        float length() const {
            return sqrt(length_squared());
        }

        Vec norm() const {
            float nor = x * x + y * y + z * z;
            if (nor > 0) {
                float invNor = 1 / sqrt(nor);
                (float)x *= invNor, (float)y *= invNor, (float)z *= invNor;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        Vec cross(const Vec&b) {
            return Vec(y*b.z-z*b.y,z*b.x-x*b.z,x*b.y-y*b.x);
        }

        float dot(const Vec& v) {
            return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
        }


    };
```

Comment: "Abstract class" implies that `Obj` has one or more pure virtual functions that `Sphere` isn't overriding. But the only virtual function in the code you've posted isn't pure, and is overridden. Are there any other virtual functions in `Obj` that you haven't shown us?

Comment: The second error implies that `Vec` doesn't have an accessible assignment operator; we'll need to see the definition of `Vec` to figure out what's wrong there.

Comment: [This code does not give the errors you describe](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=abb7b5b3230ceadc5d6bedd9111dc814-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba), please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Please give defination of vec.

Comment: Note that for `world.push_back(new Sphere` to work, `~Obj` is going to need to be `virtual`.

Comment: Just rechecking my question and there is a typo, the method intersect is indeed a pure virtual function. 
Also just checked the Vec struct and added a new operator=.
Same errors persist

Comment: Also noted that the second error happens when i try to make an attribution to an element in the abstract class, if it is in the sub-class it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was indeed in the vec file.

Can't find a reasoning about the fix, but changing the Vec struct to a class fixed all the problems.

Thanks for the help.